# Is the b coefficient in the general cosine function $f(x)=a\cos(b(x-c))+d$; the number of times the function repeats in 2 $\pi$ radians?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a series of problems in the class I am in.  The problems ask me to find the equation for a mystery graph. The b Coefficient; can be found by counting the number of maximums.  This method works good, until the graph doesn't fit nicely into $2\pi radians$.  I was wondering if there was an equation that could replace this process?

The function to the graph is $ f(x)=cos(4.2(x))$  (Red graph) and $x=2\pi$ is the (blue graph).

It is easy to find the 4.  I can do it by counting the number of maximums from points $(0,0)$ to $(2\pi,0)$.  But, I was looking for some help in find the .2.  Right now I have to draw another graph and try to match my graph with the unknown graph.  I think I can divide.  Something like $Period/2 \pi$.  I would have to know the period however, and to do this I would have to know what the coefficient b is to find the period.

[image]

Comment: I think you are just supposed to eyeball it.  The way to actually do it would be to map $x= 10\pi$ and then you'd have $4.2\times 5=21$ peaks.  (or $x =5\pi$ and you have $10\frac 12$ peaks.

Comment: I like your way.  I also,  found this out; 2pi/3/2=4.1888 approx.  That actually is the number of times the function repeats in 2 pi radians.   That to me is strange.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graph again, zoomed in.  One way to find period without having to even deal with b is to just subtract two points on the graph that are in equal spots but in different cycles.  I used maximums in my analysis because I think they are easy to find and a good way to begin.

There are maximums at (1.5,1) and (3,1)
$$Period = (3-1.5) = 1.5$$

One way to test this answer is $$b = \frac{2\pi}{(3-1.5)} = 4.18879 \phantom 
 aapprox$$ $$Period = \frac{2\pi}{4.18879} = 1.50000007 \phantom aapprox$$

In order to find 1 period, it looks like we do not even have to find b?

The general formula for period is $Period=\frac{2\pi}{b}$; it took me a little investigation to find out that period can also be found by subtraction and I was repeating a step by dividing b back into $2\pi$ radians.

[image]